# Jboss AS 7.1 and Java 1.8 -facing issues while deploying the war file

Tags: jboss7.x, war, jdk1.8-73

We are using Java 1.8 and JBoss AS 7.1 . We are not able to deploy our web application in JBoss. However, with Java 1.7 and Jboss AS 7.1 its working . Kindly guide.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1 (EAP 6.2) is not officially compatible with Java 8. If you want to use Java 8, you will need to migrate to WildFly or JBoss EAP 6.4. That is the official release for Java 8.

To make 7.1 work with Java 8, you will need to do a lot of tweaks to jboss jar versions, which is not advisable.

For details, please refer to these links:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240679?start=0&tstart=0 
https://access.redhat.com/support/configurations/jboss

Comment: Thank you sampada. It worked with JBoss EAP 6.4 as you mentioned.